Labels with ggrepel::geom_text_repel, not all labels showing
geom_text_repel doesn't display the labels for several several points where y is 0:


However, I'm able to adjust geom_text to get the labels inside the plot:

Do y'all know how to get the labels using geom_text_repel? Please find my code below:

df <- structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Maldives", "South Korea", 
"Myanmar", "Hong Kong", "Nepal", "Iran", "Pakistan", "Mongolia", 
"Sri Lanka", "Solomon Islands", "Papua New Guinea", "Philippines", 
"Vanuatu", "Fiji", "India", "Thailand", "Bangladesh", "Timor-Leste", 
"Cambodia", "Bhutan", "Indonesia", "Malaysia", "North Korea", 
"China", "Laos", "Vietnam"), events_100k = c(3.98929763342097, 
2.79873668427856, 2.62575870183105, 2.35641546264502, 1.82589571721442, 
1.5246135146153, 0.911935371211704, 0.732282427564865, 0.732173241902643, 
0.696527510433654, 0.558478859194678, 0.533576507194829, 0.437436665635902, 
0.372548653981312, 0.332483712390482, 0.33108510506144, 0.287659607432814, 
0.268114542694623, 0.243799197500219, 0.225647112496632, 0.214237892068302, 
0.161625916810053, 0.122442381076969, 0.030958809775498, 0.0305411355867934, 
0.0265856721537317, 0.0110560302970689), fatalities_100k = c(13.5403363662492, 
0, 0, 2.40734372064802, 0.00103111295706451, 0.0176525607421717, 
0.101916026586642, 0.281265249931412, 0.00121560201851201, 0.0427296136131635, 
0.126203591830265, 0.617302833700826, 0.470032459501862, 0.0340059714485864, 
0, 0.0248378913598791, 0.0649046751582995, 0.0595271434968146, 
0.0176774482270748, 0.0142209364310508, 0, 0.0134710052425114, 
0.00593122835659716, 0.0163140899407196, 0.000259674902575946, 
0.0143455539400826, 0.00158666022175559)), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df |> 
  select(-events, -fatalities) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = events_100k, y = fatalities_100k)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = country), vjust = "inward") +
  # ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = country), vjust = "inward") +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10()



Here's a bit of a hack. Add a small amount, say 0.01, to both x and y aesthetic and then subtract that amount from the labels:
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = events_100k+0.01, y = fatalities_100k+0.01)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = country), vjust = "inward") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(0.01, 0.11, 1.01, 2.01, 5.01), labels=\(x) x-0.01) + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0.01, 0.11, 1.01, 10.01), labels=\(x) x-0.01) +
  labs(x="Events (x100k)", y="Fatalities (x100K)")




The main issue is that you have some zero values in your dataset which on your chosen log scales will result in values of -Inf and hence, will be displayed on the panel border in the geom_point and the geom_text. However, it looks like +/-Inf values get dropped in geom_text_repel.
Overall I would suggest to indicate that these values are actually zero values (using e.g. color or ...), as the scale of the axis may be misleading.
And concerning the labels another option would be to replace the -Inf values for both the points and labels with a small positive value for which I use ggplot2::stage(). In the code below I have chosen a value of .00011 which results in a range of the scale similar to the one you get when you keep the -Inf values. Additionally, we have to remove the expansion of the y scale at the lower end so that the "Inf" values are still placed on the panel border.
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = events_100k, y = fatalities_100k)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(y = stage(fatalities_100k,
      after_stat = ifelse(is.infinite(log10(y)), .00011, y)
    ))
  ) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(
    expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)
  ) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(
      label = country,
      y = stage(fatalities_100k,
        after_stat = ifelse(is.infinite(log10(y)), .00011, y)
      )
    ),
    vjust = "inward"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
#> Warning in scale_y_log10(expand = c(0, 0, 0.05, 0)): log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.
#> log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.



As I figured out when answering this related question the issue is due to a change in ggrepel 0.9.5 which has been fixed in the dev version, i.e. using the dev version your code works fine:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

packageVersion("ggrepel")
#> [1] '0.9.5.9999'

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = events_100k, y = fatalities_100k)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = country),
    vjust = "inward",
    max.overlaps = Inf
  ) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
#> Warning in scale_y_log10(): log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.
#> log-10 transformation introduced infinite values.


